# Count most frequent element in an array in Minizinc

Tags: arrays, count, minizinc

It's a very simple thing that I want to do in Minizinc. I have an array of integer values, and I want to know the number of times that the most common value in it occurs. I can't figure out how to do that. I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is the most effective method, but it works, basically for each element in the array you sum the number of times that value appears in the array and store that in an auxliar array, and then take the find the maximum value that appears in the auxliar array, so in the example 14 appears 3 times so `repeats` holds 3 for every element corresponding to the 14.
At the end I added the one liner version of everything above, where instead of storing the array of `repeats` you generate it in place, its the line of `max_repeats`.

```
% count the number of times that the most common value is repeated in an array
% As an example lets make a 7 element array
% size
int : n = 7;
% index set
set of int : SET = 1..n;
% the values
array [SET] of int : x = [15,14,39,23,14,14,8];
% auxiliar variable to carry the count
array [SET] of var int : repeats;

% we will count the number of times that value repeats
constraint forall(i in SET)(repeats[i] = sum(j in SET)(x[i] = x[j]) );

% the value of the most repeated element in the array
var int : value;
% if the number of repeats of that element is the maximum 
% then value is equal to that element
constraint forall(i in SET)(repeats[i] = max(repeats) -> value = x[i]);

% this does the same but in one line
var int : max_repeats = max([sum(j in SET)(x[i] = x[j]) | i in SET]);

solve satisfy;

output ["Original values " ++ show(x) ++ "\n"] ++
       ["Number of repeats of each element " ++ show(repeats) ++ "\n"] ++ 
       ["Maximum number of repeats : " ++ show(max(repeats))];
```

```
Original values [15, 14, 39, 23, 14, 14, 8]
Number of repeats of each element [1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1]
Maximum number of repeats : 3
```

Answer (score 3):

The "classical" way of solving this problem is to use the global constriant `global_cardinality` together with `max`.

Below is one way to model this problem using these constraint; and it also shows the number that is the most frequent.

The drawback of using this approach is that one have to create a new array `gcc` (for "global cardinality count") which includes the number of occurrences for each number `0..upb` (where `upb` is the upper bound of the array `a`), and that might be quite large if there are large numbers in the array. Also, one have to be a little careful about the indices, e.g. not forget to include 0 in `gcc`.

The advantage of this approach - apart from that is might be implemented efficient in a solver - is that one can add some extra constraints on the `gcc` array: here I added the the feature to show the number that is most frequent (using `arg_max(a)`); it might be more than one such numbers and will then give multiple solutions.

```
include "globals.mzn";   

int: n = 7;
array[1..n] of int: a = [15, 14, 39, 23, 14, 14, 8];
% array[1..n] of var 0..29: a; % using decision variables

% upper value of a
int: upb = ub_array(a);

% Number of occurrences in a
array[0..upb] of var 0..n: gcc;

% max number of occurrenes
var 0..upb: z = max(gcc);

% The value of the max number of occurrences
var 0..upb: max_val = arg_max(gcc)-1;

solve satisfy;

constraint
    % count the number of occurrences in a
    global_cardinality(a, array1d(0..upb,[i | i in 0..upb]), gcc)
;

output [
    "a: \(a)\n",
    "upb: \(upb)\n",
    "gcc: \(gcc)\n",
    "z: \(z)\n",
    "max_val: \(max_val)\n",        
    "ub_array(a): \(lb_array(a))..\(ub_array(a))\n",
  ];
```

Here is the output of this model:

```
a: [15, 14, 39, 23, 14, 14, 8]
upb: 39
gcc: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
z: 3
max_val: 14
ub_array(a): 8..39
----------
==========
```